# DBpedia SPARQL endpoints for past versions

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, endpoint

Are there any DBpedia SPARQL endpoints that allow to send a query to the past versions of DBpedia?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that endpoints for different versions of the data exists.  At the very least, the DBpedia wiki article, [Accessing the DBpedia Data Set over the Web](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/OnlineAccess), doesn't seem to mention it, and I think that would be the authoritative resource.  However, the [Downloads](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads) page does list a bunch of old datasets that you can download, so if you have a fair amount of space to set up a SPARQL endpoint (e.g., with Jena Fuseki or Virtuoso), you can set one up for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use the [Triple Pattern Fragments](http://linkeddatafragments.org/) endpoints for the previous DBpedia versions. Those are provided by the [Linked Data Fragments Archive](http://mementoweb.org/depot/native/fragments/).

Here are the endpoints,

```
http://fragments.mementodepot.org/dbpedia_2_0
http://fragments.mementodepot.org/dbpedia_3_0
http://fragments.mementodepot.org/dbpedia_3_1
...
http://fragments.mementodepot.org/dbpedia_3_9
http://fragments.mementodepot.org/dbpedia_2014
http://fragments.mementodepot.org/dbpedia_2015
```

You can use the [Linked Data Fragments client](http://client.linkeddatafragments.org/) with one of the above endpoint as the data source to query previous version of DBpedia.

[image: An example]

Please note that there are some limitations with respect to the SPARQL features are supported by the LDF client.